# Wordpress API, React : this.state.project.title is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, reactjs, api

I work on a project with a Backend Wordpress and a front-end react.

But when I'm trying to get the title.rendered from the Json Data I have this :

TypeError: this.state.project.title is undefined

I can see that the data exist in the react web extension :

screenshot:

[image]

So I don't why I have this error.

Here's my code, thanks for help ;) :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {LoadingSpin} from "./LoadingSpin";

export class Project extends Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        project: [],
        loading: true
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    let dataURL = "http://api.florentbruziaux.com/wp-json/wp/v2/portefolio_projects/"+ this.props.match.params.id + "?_embed";
    fetch(dataURL)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                project: res,
                loading:false
            })
        });



}
render(){
    let ahah = this.state.project.title.rendered;
    console.log(ahah);

    return (
        <div>
            { (this.state.loading) ? <LoadingSpin/> : null}
            <h1 className="title"> </h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: You don't call componentDidMount function, so indeed, title doesn't exist

Comment: @Zooly componentDidMount is call. This is in react js. And if i replace this.state.project.title.rendered by this.state.project.title , it's working. I don't why i have an error when i try to access rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) is called after the component is mounted, so there is an initial render before it gets called. `project` will not have been loaded in this first call to `render`. You need to handle this case. You already have `state.loading`, so don't try and access anything on `project` while `loading` is true.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It's obvious when you saw it x)

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.project.fieldName` will say undefined each time because there is no project/project is not an object (you made it an array in constructor). It will be available after the data is fetched but component mounts before that.

try checking the result after fetching and only use the project data `if !loading`